# Google Plus one button android not working

Tags: android, google-plus, google-play-services

Hi Guys I have integrated a google +1 button in Android.

The main difference is I have created it inside a dialog and not inside the Activity. Below is the code I have used

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this.getContext());
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.plus_one_layout);
        dialog.setTitle("Title...");
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        plusOneButton = (PlusOneButton) dialog.findViewById(R.id.plus_one_button);
        if(!DotsCrazy.this.mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            DotsCrazy.this.mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        } 
        OnPlusOneClickListener listener = new OnPlusOneClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPlusOneClick(Intent intent) {

                if(!DotsCrazy.this.mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
                    DotsCrazy.this.mGoogleApiClient.connect();
                } else {
                    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
                }
            }
        };
        plusOneButton.initialize("http://plus.google.com/+Example",listener);
        dialog.show();
```

The problem is it always show "There was a temporary problem with your +1 Please try again later". Anybody knows the reason?

Comment: There are no error messages on the `LogCat`?

Comment: @Wakim No messages on the LogCat!!

Comment: Is `http://plus.google.com/+Example` the url you are actually using? If so you need to use a url that resolves in a HTTP 200 response.

Comment: No only when I do it from somewhere not an activity we have the problem

Comment: any lick with this problem i am having the same..